# How block a country from connection to a port

Tags: server, games

How can i block a country from going onto my port 27115

Comment: This will get you there: http://blog.laimbock.com/2013/09/22/how-to-block-countries-with-ipdeny-ip-country-blocks-ipset-and-iptables-on-el6/ (is rhel though). This might be easier: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-entier-country-using-iptables/

Comment: You can't do this, but you can get a pretty good estimate.

Answer (score 4):

The hardest part is working out which IP ranges belong to which country. There may be a way of doing this yourself but (at least for IPv4) the easiest way of doing this at the moment is using [a service like ip2location](http://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx).

They'll give you an entire list. They'll actually give you a list in iptables format.

Get what you need, run them (to block them immediately) and then save them into `/etc/network/iptables.rules` so they're picked up next boot. Or use `iptables-persistent`.

---

That will block from any port. If you want to just block a single port from that list, you'll need to condition it by adding a `--dport 27115` to each line:

```
sed -i 's/ -j/ --dport 27115 -j/' downloaded.rules
```

Then load them up.

Comment: I get a error, 
iptables v1.4.12: unknown option "--dport"